# given a bySelector how can i get the selector of this element's child?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, selenium

This is my **Html**:

```
<a class="info-button" data-voice-actions="[&quot;info&quot;, &quot;more info&quot;]" href="waze://?button=external_poi_info" id="info-button" onclick="window.location.href = this.href; return false;">
<span class="icon"></span>
<div class="btn-text">More Info</div>
</a>
```

I have a `by.org.openqa.selenium.By` selector:

```
By.cssSelector("#main > div > div.footer > div > a")
```

and I want sometimes to relate to itself, and once I want to fetch its text as in its `<div class="btn-text">More Info</div>` child element.

How can I generically get the selector of the child element from the original selector I have?

(I ask generically because this case repeats few times for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it depends on how your application works. The following assumes that the element you are looking for is always in immediate child of your `a` element, and that it always has the `.btn_text` class. You can just manipulate selectors like any string:

```
String parent_sel = "#main > div > div.footer > div > a";
String child_sel = parent_sel + " > div.btn_text";
```

Both strings can be passed to `By.cssSelector`. If my assumptions are incorrect, adapt as needed. For instance if the `div` can be a descendant of `a` without necessarily be a child of it, you could concatenate `" div.btn_text"` to get the `child_sel`.

> I want to fetch its text

In case you were looking for a selector that will give you *text*, I'll note that there is no selector you can pass to `findElement` to get *text*. This function always returns elements (or list of elements when used in its plural form). You'll have to use `getText()` on the element you get. (And in case you wonder: XPath in general *can* select text, but not when you use it through Selenium.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem you are facing clearly then two things you can do.

First,  Write a crazy selector to find it.

```
//a[@class='info-button']/..//div[.='More Info']
```

Second, Find the parent element and from there find the child element

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main > div > div.footer > div > a")).findElement(By.path("//div[.='More Info']")).something
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below xpath to locate the "info-button":

**`//div[@class='footer']//a[@class='info-button']`**

To retrieve the text "More Info", you can use the below xpath:

**`//div[@class='footer']//div[.='More Info']`**

### Edit as per OP's comment

The css-selector to get to the div element with innerHTML/text can be this:

```
#main > div > div.footer > div > a > div:nth-child(1)
```

It locates the first child element 'div' under the concerned 'a' element.

Comment: I asked how to get from one By selector to its son, not two different selectors

Comment: Please check my edited code under **'Edit as per OP's comment'**, and see if it serves your purpose